# Append serialized data to JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have one serialized form named company

```
$("#company_form").serialize();
```

And parameters in post request looks like it should

```
company[name]   company name
```

Now I need to append another serialized form to company JSON object. So far I tried to serialize `user form` same way and to add it like

```
company.user = user
```

and it appends it, but parameters are not serialized ok, they look like

```
name    name=name&email=test%40test.com
```

instead

```
user[email] test@test.com    
user[name]  name
```

If request is successful in log file I should see something like

```
{"company"=>{"name"=>"Hahn-Orn", 
             "tagline"=>"transform dynamic supply-chains", 
             "bio"=>["Tenetur non ex aliquam et. Autem velit consequatur et ea aut quos    debitis. Nulla quia impedit deserunt nesciunt. Dolores ipsam quod dolores id maiores. Atque iste quis nihil velit.", "Ducimus soluta omnis facilis illum nihil aspernatur. Aut quasi qui libero et sed. Fuga nesciunt dolorem.", "Ducimus itaque harum. Dolor officia labore rerum ullam. Veniam omnis et aut excepturi ut."]}, 
             "user"=>{"name"=>"Isabelle Schuster",
             "email"=>"jonathan_smith@example.com", 
             "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
             "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you have tried, also the actual JSON data you are working with? there is very little data for us to help you with.

Comment: Only logic thing for me was to append it like company.user = user (user is already serialized)
I need to pass parameters from ajax post to rails controller which are hashed. Controller accepts params[:user] and params[:company]. I have already wrote test for this API and data should be formatted like I've shown. {"company"=> {"company parameters"}, "user" => {"user parameters"}}

Comment: questions says you are having problem with javascript... yet there is no javascript code or html posted. What JSON are you referring too? You mention `serialize` which doesn't produce JSON. Show us the code that is relevant to problem

Comment: sorry here it is,
`var user = $(this).serialize();`
 `var company = $("#form_builder").serialize();`
 `company.user = user`
It appends me user data successfully but like url parameters. Now my question is how to append those parameters to be in serialized format, and not like URL parameters?

Comment: Solved it, I found this function for serialization 
[link](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) and append it like company.user = user